# Strange errors in mustEqual in Specs2

Tags: scala, specs2

I'm trying to write a solution to exercise 8.4 of [Scala for the impatient](http://blog.typesafe.com/free-pdf-from-typesafe-scala-for-the-impatien-64715) but am running into a strange error in my specs2 test for it.

The code looks like:

```
abstract class Item {
  def price: Double
  def description: String
}

class SimpleItem(val price: Double,  val description: String) extends Item

class Bundle(items: List[Item], val description: String) extends Item {
  def price  = (items map (_.price)).sum
}
```

And the test is:

```
"SimpleItem" should {
    "allow usage of Item methods" in {
      val si = new SimpleItem(13, "Nail")
      si.price mustEqual 13
      si.description mustEqual "Nail"
    }
}

"Bundle" should {
    "summarize item prices" {
      val l = List(new SimpleItem(2, "Fork"), new SimpleItem(3, "Knife"))
      val b = new Bundle(l, "Cutlery")
      b.price mustEqual 5
      b.description mustEqual "Cutlery" 
    }
}
```

The first test passes smoothly, but in the second I get:

```
[error]  found   : org.specs2.matcher.MatchResult[Any]
[error]  required: Int
[error]       b.description mustEqual "Cutlery"
```

I don't get it. Why would it expect an Int? Why does it work in the first test?

Comment: Got it. Missed the "in" keyword after the "summarize item prices" in the second test. A bit hard to find!